# Unable to update security settings. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, installation

While running mysql-installer-community-5.6.10 during the Configuration step, I get the error:

Unable to update security settings. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

and the configuration fails.

... and the password is being set during the previous step of the configuration process, so I don't see how it possibly could be wrong...

I have tried turning off the Windows Firewall but it has not helped.

Could anybody help me out with this?

Comment: What is the password you gave?

Answer (score 16):

I just had this problem. The prior install screen had asked for the Current root password. But this was the first MySQL install on the machine.

Answer: when asked for the Current root password, leave that field blank. Then the server installed ok.

Comment: If you're looking to do a "fresh install", you must delete c:\ProgramData\MySQL folder and c:\Program Files\MySql folder before you do a new install. ProgramData is a hidden folder.

Comment: When configuring the new install it requires a root password.  Can not leave it blank.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and my first install of mysql ever. For me it was the fact that I did not run the .msi installation file as administrator. By launching through a command prompt that was run as admin the issue was resolved. This is on Windows 7.

Also, I uninstalled twice for this issue. Once I deleted the (nonexistent) serverdata. In that case, the reinstall did not ask for Current root password. When I did not delete serverdata, the Current root password was indeed asked at reinstall. So you can bypass Current root password I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. This helped me
C:\ProgramData\MySql\
Remove folder "MySQL Server" and all conf files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MySQL saves its configuration data in a different location and that includes your old root password.  If you're going to re-install MySQL you have to first delete this old configuration data which can be found in:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL
```

You may have to tell windows to show hidden files and folders because this folder is hidden by default.